# iphone tableview scrolling issue

Tags: iphone, scroll, tableview

I have a tableview with imageviews and textviews in each cell. When my view is loaded one of the textviews is invisible. But when I start scrolling the textview appears, so that my view looks as it is supposed to look. Does anyone know why this is happening?
P.S. I have read about reusing cells when scrolling so I have been very careful to construct my cells correctly.

Comment: can you please give some more detail/code

Comment: My code is really huge and complicated, but the main thing is that I am constructing my cells depending on data I receive from server, and count the height of the cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without code, no one can give you a exact answer. But for a guess....

Is your data is getting populated after your table call cellForRowAtIndexPath? When the cell populates the first time, no data, so the cell is in it's unformatted state. By the time you can interact with the table and scroll it off and on screen (which calls cellForRowAtIndexPath again), the data has been populated and so the cell looks as expected.

You can test this by putting a breakpoint in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method and check to see if your data objects are initialized or still set to nil.

Comment: I have tried checking, but the data is complete by the time cellFroRowAtIndexPath is called.

Comment: I've thought about other pitfalls which could cause this behavior, but none seem realistic. I'd need to see code to help more.